# HTML Wordpress Menu - hover removes text?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have developed a website in wordpress, using a theme called - the restaurant. 
For some reason the Menu is misbehaving and the client cannot view it.

It think the problem is something to do with the rollover bit, as you can see from the image below this is the problem.

http://i40.tinypic.com/1z6dpja.jpg

Weird thing is it is working on all my browsers.

Any suggestions. x

```
/* begin ---------------------------------------- menu */


 #mainmenu {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: 81px;
width: 100%;
}

 #mainmenu .wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 990px;
 }
 #menu-bg {
width: 990px;
height: 53px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('images/menu_bg.png') no-repeat;
 }

#menu-left {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 0px;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
background-image: url(images/menu_left.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

#menu-right {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
right: 0px;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
background-image: url(images/menu_right.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

 #menu-container {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 15px;
width: 960px;
height: 43px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('images/patern_sharp.png');
float: left;
border-top: #000 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
 }

#mainmenu ul.menu {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 150px;
 }

#mainmenu .dropdown_arrow {
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 19px;
right: 10px;
border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
 }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover .dropdown_arrow, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-     

 menu.current-menu-item .dropdown_arrow, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-
 menu-   parent .dropdown_arrow {
top: 21px;
 }

#mainmenu ul.menu li {
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0 3px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
 }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu {
padding-right: 30px;
}

#mainmenu ul.menu li a {
color: #fff;
}

 #mainmenu ul.menu li:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li.current-menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu  
 li.current-menu-parent{
background: #fff;
padding: 17px 14px 18px 14px;
margin: -3px 3px 0 3px;
border-top: #dedede 1px solid;
border-right: #dedede 1px solid;
border-left: #dedede 1px solid;
 }

#mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-  
 menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu.current-menu-parent {
padding-right: 29px;
 }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li.has-sub-menu:hover {
padding-bottom: 24px;
 }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
top: 55px;  left: -1px;
background: #fff;
display: none;
padding: 10px 0;
border-right: #dedede 1px solid;
6border-bottom: #dedede 1px solid;
border-left: #dedede 1px solid;
  }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: inline-block;
  }

 #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li {
clear: both;
height: auto;
width: 200px;
padding: 10px 15px;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
display: block;
  }

#mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li.current-menu-item, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu        
 li:hover {
padding: 10px 15px;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
background: #eee;
 }

#mainmenu ul.menu li:hover ul.sub-menu li a, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
height: auto;
 }

#mainmenu ul.menu li a:hover, #mainmenu ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

/* end ---------------------------------------- menu */

Comment: We'll need html and/or link to site.

Comment: Like @elclanrs says. What do you expect to see? Has your client cleared his cache?

Answer (score 1):

You've set the text color to white in this entry:

```
    #mainmenu ul.menu li a {
color: #fff;
}
```

"color:" Refers to text color, not the color of the background.